# Macro to copy and change set numbers Excel

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

so am working on a spreadsheet to simplify logging of data. However it's quite a tedious process of copy, paste & change. Is there a way I can create a Macro to copy the following:

```
=IF(Trade2!I16=99,0,Trade2!I15)
```

Paste it the cell directly below but as

```
=IF(Trade3!I16=99,0,Trade3!I15)
```

Beyond this it needs to be copied 100 times. Am at 15 typing it manually each time and losing the will to live haha
This seems insanely simple but everything am trying is leading to a massive mess, am good at getting the spreadsheet side working but the coding isn't my strong point.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: if you fix the one cell in place using **$** signs, you can just copy and paste:  e.g. you're first formula would be `=IF(Trade1!$I$16=99,0,Trade1!I15)` - when you copy it, Excel will know to not change the 1st cell reference, but to change the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this formula:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Trade"&ROWS(A$1:A1)&"!I16")=99,0,INDIRECT("Trade"&ROWS(A$1:A1)&"!I15"))
```

this returns:

```
=IF(Trade1!I16=99,0,Trade1!I15)
```

But you can now copy it down, and the sheet number increases.

The ROWS formula functions as a counter as you copy it down. The INDIRECT formula returns a reference to a sheet.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help its much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean but try this

```
Sub Main()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10000
        Range("A" & i).Formula = "=IF(Trade2!I" & i + 1 & "=99, 0, Trade2!I" & i & ")"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Loop not required ;) This will do... `Range("A1:A100").Formula = "=IF(Trade3!I1=99,0,Trade3!I1)"` or whatever formula goes in `A1`

Comment: Very close, with a little work I managed to get it working how I wanted. Just for your reference the actual code should have been Sub Main()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        Range("O" & i).Formula = "=IF(Trade" & i + 1 & "!I16=99, 0, Trade" & i + 1 & "!I15)"
    Next i

End Sub